# UGC rating stars

Tags: 2011, ugc

We've integrated UGC into our 2011 SP1 HR1 implementation and I've noticed something odd.

A single user has rated a component 5 - but in the GUI only 4 stars are shown!

[image: Raing screenshot]

I've checked the db and there is only one rating of 5 so the **Average Rating** is correct - but only 4 stars - thats a bug right?

**UPDATE**

In addition, when we view ratings through the Control Room I can see information like:

```
Average Rating: 5
Individual Ratings: 1

neil gave a rating of 4.166667
```

There seems to be a logic bug here - one rating of 5 != 4.166667!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure `RatingMinimum` and `RatingMaximum` values for specific dataSource in `DataSources.xml` file.

5 starts does not necessarily mean rating of 5 possible points. It just indicates maximum rating value. If RatingMaximum configured as 10, the 5 starts will indicate rating of 10.

From your example I can assume that maximum rating is configured as 6 (5/4.1666...67 == 6/5).

Otherwise, it is indeed a bug.

Comment: Good shout - for some strange reason our minimum is -1 and our max is 5. Am I ok to change this given we have existing ratings? I wont get some at 4.166667 and others at 4?

Comment: I don`t have a 2011Sp1Hr1 db instance to check, but I think it was not changed since. In Database only Rating value, so as Average item rating value are stored. Make sure that the new bounds you set will fit existing ratings values in DB, and feel free to change it, other values should have to be recalculated. I think it is clear, but still, keep in mind, if you change the minimum rating value from -1 to 0, it will automatically adjust overall items rating.